# How to test that the list Count is a certain value?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit.net, nsubstitute

I am trying to test one of my methods by seeing how many results are being passed into my `Save method`. The pertinent line is:

```
await paymentSampleRepository.Received()
            .SaveSamplesAsync(Arg.Do<List<PaymentSamplePopulation>>(x => 
                                  Assert.Equal(sampleCount, x.Count())
                              ), modifiedBy);
```

I am obviously missing something about how to test this... how do I test the `Count` of what's being passed into `SaveSamplesAsync`

This is always showing as passing. I've tried `sampleCount` and `sampleCount + 1` in the `Assert` and they both show as passing!

If need be, I can show the whole test method.

Comment: Show a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Answer (score 1):

Reference [Actions with argument matchers](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/actions-with-arguments/)

Assuming following

```
public interface ILoader {
    Task LoadAsync(List<int> data);
}

public class SystemUnderTest {
    private readonly ILoader loader;
    public SystemUnderTest(ILoader loader) {
        this.loader = loader;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(int count) {
        var data = Enumerable.Range(1,count).ToList();
        await loader.LoadAsync(data);
    }

}
```

A test would look like this

```
//Arrange
var expected = 2;
var actual = -1;

var loader = Substitute.For<ILoader>();
loader.LoadAsync(Arg.Do<List<int>>(x => actual = x.Count);

var sut = new SystemUnderTest(loader);

//Act
await sut.InvokeAsync(expected);

//Assert
Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
```